# How to configure as a non-blocking unique_lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking, blocking

I have found in the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html) that a `unique_lock` can try "to acquire the lock in a non-blocking fashion".

Is it the `unique_lock`'s thread that isn't blocked as it tries to acquire the lock in the "non-blocking fashion"?  If so, does it simply fail gracefully?  Will `unlock`?

Also, since [`notify_one`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable.notify_one) doesn't throw, does that mean that if it cannot notify, it will also fail gracefully?

If the `unique_lock` can be set not to wait for a successful `lock` but fail gracefully and move on with graceful failures for `unlock` and `notify_one`, how can a `unique_lock` be set this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `boost::unique_lock lock(my_lockable, boost::try_to_lock);` should do the trick.

`lock.owns_lock()` will return true if the lock were acquired. If it wasn't acquired you should not attempt to release it.

It should always be safe to call `notify_one` even if no condition is waiting for it.

Comment: Is it correct that `notify_one` will fail gracefully?  I'm still very noob.  Thank you so very much in advance!